# CasperJS and Magento testing

Tags: testing, casperjs

Anyone using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) for functional testing in Magento? By functional testing I mean testing the frontend/backend for various usage scenarios like checkout, register a new account, creating a credit memo and so on.

What are your use cases?

**Update:**

Let's hope that after [Testing Magento](http://slidesha.re/19et8cE) presentation, more developers will start using CasperJS

Comment: Not Casper, doing BDD with Codeception currently. I'm interested in hearing some Casper or Phantom workflows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course we use CasperJS on Magento.

You can see some tests on https://github.com/jacquesbh/hackathon-casperjs/ .

Don't hesitate to participate on your own fork of this repo.

Bye

Jacques

Comment: Merci Jacques, très utile.